# Can't click a NavigationLink in List (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, swiftui

I can't click on a `NavigationLink` in a `List` after the Xcode update to Beta 3. The row is gray for some reason.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
List {
        Section {

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("ProfileView")) {
                Text("Profil")
            }

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Einstellungen")) {
                Text("Einstellungen und Datenschutz")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have this inside a `NavigationView`?

Comment: Oh right I don't have that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List should be inside NavigationView,

Update your code as mentioned below,

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        Section {

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("ProfileView")) {
                Text("Profil")
            }

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Einstellungen")) {
                Text("Einstellungen und Datenschutz")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `NavigationLink` is inside a `NavigationView`